# VBA function result type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run as a macro a custom Excel function `XpathOnUrl` from the add-in called SeoTools by Niels Bosma. The function runs fine and it seems that I am able to store its result in a variable. This variable can then be correctly output to an Excel cell, but when I try to look for a string in it in the next part of the macro, I get the error `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`. From what I understand from [here](http://seoforums.nielsbosma.se/index.php?p=/discussion/626/calling-seo-tools-from-vba), the function returns an array, but when I try to access it as the first item of the array, I get the same error. I tried to convert the variable into a string with `CStr`, but no luck there either. What am I missing?

Here's the problematic part of the code:

```
WebSite = Sheet1.Range("A1")
contactPage = Application.Run("XPathOnUrl", WebSite, "//a[contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),""contact"")]", "href")

MsgBox TypeName(contactPage) 'trying to find out the data type results in 'Error'

    If Left(contactPage(0), 4) = "http" Then

        Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = contactPage

    ElseIf InStr(contactPage, "/") = 1 Then

        Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = WebSite & contactPage

    End If
```

Just to make it clear: the problem starts only with conditional statements. If I assign the value of the variable directly to a cell like this `Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = contactPage`, it outputs the correct result.

Comment: What does `contactPage` look like when you view it in the `Locals` window? Does it appear as an array that is populated and indexed?

Comment: You have a typo in your first line. change `WebSite = Sheet1.Range("A1)"` to `WebSite = Sheet1.Range("A1")`

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping me discover the `Locals` window. Looks like a very useful tool. And to your question, `contactPage` appears as Type: variant/error and Value: error 2015

Comment: If Msgbox shows `Error` than ContactPage probably contains an error ... Hmmm, I see you already found that out from the Locals window

Comment: @JLILIAman You are right, I made a mistake when adjusting the cell names to look more consistent. In the actual code the syntax is correct

Comment: Your application.run is not returning an array to your contact page variant.

Comment: What's `contact` in `Application.Run("XPathOnUrl", WebSite, "//a[contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),""contact"")]", "href")`? Can you supply the declaration of the `XPathOnURL` function?

Comment: @JLILIAman This is what I suspected. But how can I find out what it actually returns and how do I convert it into a string?

Comment: @JLILIAman The function works like this: XpathOnUrl("URL",Xpath). This particular `Xpath` is searching for all the occurrences of the string "contact" in urls on the page defined in the variable `WebSite`, while making sure that it is converted to lowcase

Comment: Does it return the value of `contactpage`?

Comment: It actually does this way `Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = contactPage`, but not when looking for a string in it

Comment: You need to understand so far `contactpage` is a empty variant because `application.run` is not assigning anything in `contactpage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a easy workaround:

Make `XpathURL` spit its return to a range. Then, use `Range.value` to assign the return to a `contactpage` and clear the range using `.Clearcontents` property. I think `Application.Run` is not letting `XpathURL` return get to `contactpage`.

Edit: Added the comment below:

```
 Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Application.Run("XPathOnUrl", WebSite, "//a[contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),""contact"")]", "href") 
contactPage = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
```

Comment: So for whoever might need this in the future, I have changed the code a bit as described in @JLILI Aman's answer, so now the variable `contactPage` is defined like this: `Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Application.Run("XPathOnUrl", WebSite, "//a[contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),""contact"")]", "href")` and then `contactPage = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Formula and FormulaR1C1 functions? Just my assumptions.

Try and let us know if it helped.

```
Sheet1.Range("B1").Formula = WebSite & contactPage
```

or

```
Sheet1.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = WebSite & contactPage
```

What does the `MsgBox TypeName(contactPage)` display?

Comment: How can `Sheet1.Range("B1").Formula = WebSite & contactPage` return a formula if it starts with a string from the variable `WebSite`?

Comment: It was just my assumption as I said before. I don't know how, but Formula works for me instead of Range.Value.